# count(distinct col1) not giving correct count

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a below table

**id   date1**

1   1973-07-06

1   null

1   1994-01-20

1   1973-07-06

1   1980-03-12

1   1994-01-20

2   1960-10-17

2   1996-12-12

2   1996-12-12

2   2000-02-18

2   null

2   null

2   1960-10-17

2   1960-10-17

2   null

I need to find unique date1 value count for each id

Query i am using is as follows

```
select id,count(distinct date1) as col1
from iop
group by id
```

this query is giving me the wrong result as

**id  col1**

1     4

2     4

However I should get

**id  col1**

1     3

2     3

Comment: `NULL` still gets counted because there's a row there, which is why you get 4. If you don't want to include those rows filter them out using a WHERE clause.

Comment: ok now i am using the query

Comment: 1973-07-06, null, 1994-01-20 and 1980-03-12 is **four** distinct values for an id of 1, so it's not increasing the count by one. The query does exactly what it should, it's just not working how you think it works or how you want it to.

Comment: select id,count(distinct date1)
from iop
where date1 is not null
group by id --this is also giving the count of 4

Comment: what should i write in where clause to get the correct count

Comment: you can add 'WHERE date1 IS NOT NULL'

But on my testing machine,your code it give me: 3, 3
from BOL :  DISTINCT

    Specifies that COUNT returns the number of unique nonnull values.

Comment: I think your [date1] have some "mistery" values .
Try to check your distinct values , just for one ID ,like this:


    SELECT [date1]
FROM iop
WHERE [ID]= 1 AND [date1] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY [date1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the query is counting the null value, try this:

```
select id,count(distinct date1) as col1
from iop
WHERE date1 NOT LIKE  'NULL'
group by id
```